# How to connect to unix socket from php

Tags: php, sockets, http, unix

How can I communicate HTTP to unix domain sockets in php.
 I am looking for a library simmilar to this: [requests-unixsocket](https://github.com/msabramo/requests-unixsocket) but this is for python, I need for php. 
Kindly give example code if possible.

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/834307/can-curl-send-requests-to-sockets/925610#925610) answer curl has `--unix-socket` option but this is not supported in php-curl from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33869760/1644614) answer.

I found [Socket Client for PHP HTTP](https://github.com/php-http/socket-client) library for php but cant figure out how to use it.
Kindly share similar libraries.

**Edit:**
From [this](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/01/08/curl-7-40-0-unix-domain-sockets-and-smb/) blog, can we somehow use `CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH` option in php ?

Comment: Sorry if my answer mislead you in any way, you _can_ connect to unix sockets in PHP, it just seem you cannot from php-curl. You could either use command-line curl or direct socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

try stream_socket_client.

```
resource stream_socket_client ( string $remote_socket [, int &$errno [, string &$errstr [, float $timeout = ini_get("default_socket_timeout") [, int $flags = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT [, resource $context ]]]]] )
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be late here but here is how it's done using `CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH`.
for other users who visit finding an answer for this.

```
    $socket = '/var/run/docker.sock';

    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH, $socket);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 256);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000000);

    $writeFunction = function ($ch, $string) {
        echo $string;
        $length = strlen($string);
        printf("Received %d byte\n", $length);
        flush();
        return $length;
    };
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $writeFunction);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http:/localhost/version");
    curl_exec($ch);
```