# How to configure php to log to a listening socket?

Tags: php, sockets, logging

Is it possible to configure php to send errors to a listening socket instead of sending to file?

I am speaking of *Unix sockets*. Not *WebSockets*

I am already able to code a go app to act as a listening socket. I want my app to receive php logs.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51019379/5897602) help? Looks like cURL can be used with the [`CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option. Looks to require PHP 7.0^

Comment: @Jaquarh That's how to write to the socket from the script, it doesn't help with making error messages go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to configure it directly. The only configuration option for where to send log messages is [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log). It can be set to either `syslog` or the pathname of the log file.

You could do it indirectly. The pathname could point to a named pipe, and you can have another process that reads from the named pipe and writes to the socket.

Or you could have the Go app listen on the named pipe instead of a socket.